# I need datasheet for the marking 721P K1N1, it is a 5 Pin SOT-23-5 package component

Tags: identification, sot23

It is used in Automotive vehicle on Power Electronics Module. I don't know which manufacturer it belongs to.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJxPk.png

Comment: Welcome! The image is broken.

Comment: Ganesh Thiva - Hi, As commented, your image link doesn't seem useful (it seems to be a yellow square). For identification questions, please follow [these guidelines](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6710/component-identification-question-guidelines). At the moment, your question does not include the required information as explained at that link. Please [edit] your question and add that information. Also, since you are new here, please see the main site rules in the [tour] & [help], as the rules here differ from typical forums. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "721P" marking and claimed package matches with a [RUNIC Tech RS721PXF](https://www.run-ic.com/en/upload/goods/20220627/202206271716133105.pdf) Op Amp.

[image]

If you provide a picture of the surrounding components, I can check if the pin out and device type is plausible, otherwise you have to check for yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the support bro, it matches... how did you found it brother!! can you give me some ideas

Comment: @GaneshThiva Your welcome. If this is the correct part, please accept the answer by clicking the check mark. I found it by simply google searching 'SOT-23-5 "721P" markings'. Sometimes it's that easy ;) (usually not though).

Comment: sure bro..thanks a lot... can i get your linkedin user name!! so that i can follow u